# Java String Bubble Sorting

Tags: java, sorting, bubble-sort

I need help sorting this array in alphabetical order using the bubble sort algorithm.

My code is:

```
public class Strings
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String tempStr;


        System.out.print("Enter the strings > ");
        String s1 = new String(reader.nextLine());

        String[] t1 = s1.split(", ");

        for (int t=0; t<t1.length-1; t++)
        {
           for (int i = 0; i<t1.length -1; i++)
           {
               if(t1[i+1].compareTo(t1[1+1])>0)
               {
                   tempStr = t1[i];
                   t1[i] = t1[i+1];
                   t1[i+1] = tempStr;
                }
            }

        }

        for(int i=0;i<t1.length;i++)
        {
            System.out.println(t1[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The code compiles, but it does not sort alphabetical. Please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to implement bubble sort? This looks fishy to me `t1[i+1].compareTo(t1[1+1])` especially the `1+1` part. Also, make sure you're using the right indices in the array in your for loops.

Comment: I can't use any sort method. I have to manually sort the strings alphabetical.

Comment: Whichever type of "manual" sorting  you choose, it has some name. Just read up on them. You're probably going to end up with either bubble sort or insertion sort. Bubble sort isn't some sort of "sort method". You'll sort it out, sort of.

Comment: Is this the answer you are looking for? If so, please accept it so others with a similar questions will know the answer. Its how the community is based. @user2844549

Answer (score 2):

You have three errors in your code.

The first error is in the inner for loop, in the place where you do the check statement, it should be `i < t1.length - t -1` not `i < t1.length -1`. You subtract t because you do not want to loop through the whole array again, only the first part of it.

The second and third errors are in the if statement. You need to turn the greater than symbol into a lesser than symbol, because the way you have the compareTo method set up, it will return a negative number.

The other error in this line is that in the compareTo parameter you put `1 + 1` it actually should be just `i`, because you want one less than the object it is comparing to.

The fixed working code is below (Comments are what you originally had):

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        String tempStr;

        System.out.print("Enter the strings > ");
        String s1 = new String(reader.nextLine());

        String[] t1 = s1.split(", ");

        for (int t = 0; t < t1.length - 1; t++) {
            for (int i= 0; i < t1.length - t -1; i++) {
                if(t1[i+1].compareTo(t1[i])<0) {
                    tempStr = t1[i];
                    t1[i] = t1[i + 1];
                    t1[i + 1] = tempStr;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < t1.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(t1[i]);
        }
   }
```

Comment: I'm sure it'll help in the short term, unless he actually wants to do his own homework.

Comment: I tried to explain what he did wrong with his code @DaveNewton.

Answer (score 0):

please change

```
String[] t1 = s1.split(", ");
```

to

```
String[] t1 = s1.split("");
```

This will solve the issue.

Comment: This is nonsense. It may solved your problem, because your input was wrong, but that doesn't mean that would this solves someone elses issue.